# Accessing different host's docker containers via portainer

Tags: networking, docker, containers, docker-swarm, docker-networking

I have a few containers (running various services) on my ubuntu server and i manage those containers via portainer, which is also one of these containers. I would like to also manage a pihole container (running on a different server (raspberry pi)) from that same portainer interface. The machines are on the same local, private, network.

I've read about people proxying/exposing the docker unix socket over tcp etc but that seems risky and unsecure and more like a workaround. I tried reading up on docker swarms but that seems like a different use case but i could be wrong.

Any help is very appreciated :)

Comment: What else would you use, if not TCP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deploy [portainer/agent](https://hub.docker.com/r/portainer/agent) and access it via the agent url

```yml
  portainer_agent:
    image: portainer/agent
    container_name: portainer-agent
    ports:
    - "9001:9001"
    volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    - /var/lib/docker/volumes:/var/lib/docker/volumes
    restart: unless-stopped
```